# How to Add/Update/View tags for the user in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have a following requirement regarding tags and users.

- Tags should be searched based on the email address specified in the
  text box.
- Tags available for the particular user to be displayed based on the
  email address after search.
- There should be option to add/modify multiple tags for the users
  based on their emailid specified in the text box.

I have done coding for adding the tags to the users as follows

**JSP:**

```
<portlet:actionURL var="addTagsURL"  name="addTags"/>    
<aui:form action="<%=addTagsURL%>" method="post" name="submit">
    <aui:input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" label="Email Address">
        <aui:validator name="required" />       
    </aui:input>
    <liferay-ui:asset-tags-error />
    <aui:input name="tags" type="assetTags" />
    <div>
        <liferay-ui:asset-tags-selector />
    </div>
    <aui:input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></aui:input>
</aui:form>
```

**Action class:**

```
public void addTags(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse){
        String emailAddress=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "emailAddress");
        log_.info("user email address from form========>"+emailAddress);
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);        
        User user;
        try {
            user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), emailAddress);
            ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest);
            AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(user.getUserId(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),"com.liferay.portal.model.User", user.getUserId(),null, serviceContext.getAssetTagNames());
            log_.info("user email address========>"+user.getEmailAddress());
            log_.info("UserId is=========>"+user.getUserId());
            String tags[]=serviceContext.getAssetTagNames();
            log_.info("Tags are====>"+tags.toString());         
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

By above code i can have UI to add the tags to the users.But if i want to delete the tags for particular user how can i do and if any API or tags are there please guide me.

For retrieval purpose of tags based on the emailAddress specified in the textbox, I just using ServiceBuilder concept by querying form tables AssetEntry_AssetTags.Is it correct way of doing to display tags available for a given emailAddress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get asset tags associated with user entity by below API method.
`com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetTagLocalServiceUtil`

`public static java.util.List<com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetTag> getTags(
        long classNameId, long classPK)`

Where classpk would be userId and classNameId would be of User class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.Yes it helped me for retrieving the tags associated to the user.Do you have any idea to modify tags for the user like removal of existing tags and adding the new tags then click on save.

Comment: @LaxmanDeepak You should update your question or close this question by accepting it and creating new question by details what you had already tried?